# fullname field unable to validate using jquery

Tags: jquery, regex, jquery-validate

**I need 2 things: (regarding jquery fields validation)**

```
a) I need each field validated as 'onblur' instead of 'onsubmit'
b) Iam unable to validate 'fullname' field...
```

**Below are the validations required for the 'FullName' field:**

- only letters a to z (lower case), "-" (dash or hyphen) and " "
  (space) are allowed,
- the "-" (dash) AND " " (space) letters MUST be entered,
- the "-" or the " " letter must not be either the first or the last
  letter entered,
- "-" must not be the immediate neighbour or adjacent (before or after)
  to a " ",
- "-" or " " must not be the immediate neighbour (adjacent) to itself.

**here is my code that I have tried:** http://jsfiddle.net/ea829/13/

please someone look into this..

Answer (score 0):

use this regex `^[a-z](?=.* )(?=.*-)[a-z -]+[a-z]$` to validate 1,2,3 (must be match)

and `((  )|(- )|( -)|(--))` to validate 4,5 (must not be match)

Comment: are these 2 lines correct?      var validCharactersRegex = new RegExp(/^[a-z](?=.* )(?=.*-)[a-z -]+[a-z]$/);    
    var lettermustbeeitherthefirst = new RegExp(/(( )|(- )|( -)|(--))/);